# UIButton not receiving touch after superview rotate

Tags: objective-c, ios, caanimation

I am working with a UICollectionView, and I have defined a custom UICollectionViewCell by subclassing that class. The initializer of the class defines two views, just like this:

```
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProtelViewCellFlipped" owner:self options:nil];

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0);
    [flippedView.layer setTransform:transform];
    [flippedView setHidden:YES];
    [self addSubview:flippedView];

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProtelViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:selfView];
    [selfView.layer setZPosition:1];
```

where flippedView is a view defined by the "ProtelViewCellFlipped" xib file, and selfView is the view defined in the "ProtelViewCell" xib file. The view hierarchy is like this: [the view hierarchy http://massimomarra.altervista.org/gerarchia.png](http://massimomarra.altervista.org/gerarchia.png)

The thing is that the flipped view is rotated (as if it was the other side of the "selfView" view) by a `CATransform3D`, and then it is hidden. And that's all right, it works.

The `selfView` view has a UIButton on it. In the bottom right corner of the view. If I press that button, this method gets triggered:

```
- (void)infoButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *animationKey = (selfView.layer.zPosition > flippedView.layer.zPosition)? @"forward" : @"backwards";
    CGFloat animationDuration = 0.3;

    if (selfView.layer.zPosition > flippedView.layer.zPosition)
        [self.layer removeAllAnimations];

    CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
    [rotation setValue:animationKey forKey:@"id"];
    rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI];
    rotation.duration = animationDuration;
    rotation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    rotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    [self.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:animationKey];

    [self performSelector:@selector(flipLayers) withObject:nil afterDelay:animationDuration/2];
}
```

So that the `self` view is rotated with an animation. Also, during the animation gets called this method:

```
- (void)flipLayers
{
    [selfView setHidden:!selfView.hidden];
    [flippedView setHidden:!selfView.hidden];

    [selfView.layer setZPosition:flippedView.layer.zPosition];
    [flippedView.layer setZPosition:(1-selfView.layer.zPosition)];
}
```

so that the `flippedView` becomes visible (and `selfView` hides), and the zPosition of his layer becomes higher than `selfView`.

So now I have the `flippedView` visible, and it is displayed correctly. It has also a button, but to trigger his action I have to tap in another position: [flipped view scheme: i have to tap where the button "was" before the rotation http://massimomarra.altervista.org/s03KRJAUk7C_nP3yTXb7TBQ.png](http://massimomarra.altervista.org/s03KRJAUk7C_nP3yTXb7TBQ.png)

It seems like the rotation just modifies the graphics of the view, but not the content.
Can you please help me?

Thanks to you all in advance!!

Answer (score 4):

transform the button back to identity before change orientation

something like this:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{

    oneButton.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

I don't know why but it seems working